# Side by side code comparison with either jQuery or PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for a library that will allow me to compare 2 code snippets.

Said snippets will be in LUA.

I want to show differences between them a la GitHub. Think a split screen showing what's been added, what's been deleted, the usual.

I've searched around and nothing seems too satisfying, most answers I've come across mention libraries 3-4 years old.

I'm stuck with either using jQuery or PHP to do the comparison.

Basically, it has to "look pretty" and be accurate.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want it online and not as a desktop application?

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne Yep, I need to integrate it in a site.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to write a plugin yourself or would you prefer an already written one?

Comment: I'd honestly prefer one already written. No reason to reinvent the wheel. Besides I'm sure I'd miss somethings along the way resulting in some god knows what weird behavior.

Comment: I had a little look around and I agree they do look pretty old, and not very nice looking. Would you like me to put one together for you and link it in an answer, it'll be purely JSON parameters into a jQuery interface and CSS to change the entire behaviour of how it looks

Comment: No sure if you're joking or not. Either way, hell yeah I would. But it'd drop the json part, no need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Not joking! and the interface for the function would be too large if I didn't provide the option for a JSON array. The parameters wouldn't be required but there if you wanted to change them

Comment: Fair enough. Well...thanks I guess. I've never had somebody write a library for me, don't even know what to say...

Comment: Its cool! I enjoy writing jQuery stuff, gives me something to do in my spare time haha. 

Will the differences need to be in the text area or displayed much like GitHub or StackOverflow do where they are plain text. Almost like 2 `textarea`'s for the code and 2 `div`'s for the difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81888/discussion-between-andrew-and-zach-ross-clyne).